# media queries in css not working in phone devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to create a web page and I've added some media queries for managing how the website looks depending on the width of the device. The problem is that, for example, a media query set to affect devices under 800px DOES work if you resize chrome in your computer, but it DOES NOT work in phone devices, even though the condition (less than 800px) is fullfilled.
I'm including a link to the website so that you can check this out on your computer/phone

https://serchpics.github.io/Homepage/

I would really appreciate the help because I can't figure out why this might be happening. Thx! :)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question to meet those guidelines and include a [repro] for debugging details. Question and answers always must be self-containing and not relay on external resoruces. As such a link to your website is an inacceptable substitute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site doesn't have a viewport set, so it zooms out every time you load the page.

You can set a viewport by putting this code under your `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

[You can learn more about viewports here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: wow that was so simple yet effective, thx so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into `<head>` section:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: thx! same answer as bellow, super accurate :)